# Change x labels of matplotlib graph to particular words using ax object

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

given the following data:

```py
mock_data_x = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
mock_data_y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
mock_data_val = [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
    "d",
    "e",
    "d",
    "e",
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
    "d",
    "a",
    "b",
    "e",
    "c",
]
df_mock = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=mock_data_x, y=mock_data_y, v=mock_data_val,))
```

which looks as:

```
    x  y  v
0   1  1  a
1   1  2  b
2   1  3  c
3   1  4  d
4   1  5  e
5   2  1  d
6   2  2  e
7   2  3  a
8   2  4  b
9   2  5  c
10  3  1  d
11  3  2  a
12  3  3  b
13  3  4  e
14  3  5  c
```

I can create the following plot:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5))

x_axis_labels = ["one", "two", "three"]

values = df_mock["v"].unique()
for val in values:
    dt = df_mock[df_mock["v"].eq(val)]
    ax.scatter(dt["x"], dt["y"])
    ax.plot(dt["x"], dt["y"])

positions = [1, 2, 3]
labels = ["r", "q"]
_ = plt.xticks(positions, x_axis_labels)
```

Which looks as:

[image]

I feel as though there should be an alternative to the line

```py
_ = plt.xticks(positions, x_axis_labels)
```

Something which actually uses the `ax` object rather than `plt`.

I've looked in `dir(ax)`, and `dir(ax.xaxis)`, and it's not obvious what I
should use to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent for `ax` is:

```
ax.set_xticks(positions)
ax.set_xticklabels(x_axis_labels)
```

and you get pretty much the same plot.

However, for this case, you can simply use `map` and pandas' plot function:

```
maps = {p:v for p,v in zip(positions, x_axis_labels)}

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))
(df_mock.set_index(['x','v'])['y']
     .unstack()
     .rename(index=maps)
     .plot(marker='o', ax=ax)
)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks, the alt is nice though it makes the y-axis have `0.5` rather than just ints